# missing 'error' handler on this Redis client

Tags: redis, nestjs

It's really an odd issue I cannot detect, here's my adapter.

```
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-adapter';
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { IAppConfig, IRedisConfig } from '@app/app-config';

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  private adapterConstructor: ReturnType<typeof createAdapter>;

  constructor(app: INestApplication, private configService: ConfigService<IAppConfig>) {
    super(app);
  }

  async connectToRedis(): Promise<void> {
    const redisConfig = this.configService.get<IRedisConfig>('redis');
    if (redisConfig) {
      const { host, port } = redisConfig;
      const pubClient = createClient({ url: `redis://${host}:${port}` });
      const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

      await Promise.all([pubClient.connect(), subClient.connect()]);

      this.adapterConstructor = createAdapter(pubClient, subClient);
    }
  }

  createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): any {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options);
    server.adapter(this.adapterConstructor);
    return server;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this node-redis v4 or v3?

Comment: ``"@socket.io/redis-adapter": "^7.1.0",``
``"redis": "^4.0.4",``
`` "socket.io": "^4.4.0",
    "socket.io-redis": "^6.1.1",``

Comment: I would bet this is an issue with `redis v4`. Can you downgrade it to v3 and see if it works?

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: @iMe an issure related to aws encryption

Answer (score 2):

Here **error** handler not added to the code.

```
pubClient.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err.message);
});

subClient.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```